# How to use bleachbit to clean other mounted drives and specific folders?

Tags: command-line, cleanup, bleachbit

I use bleachbit to clean (deep scan) my home directory:

```
bleachbit -c --preset
```

But I want to use bleachbit to clean my other mounted drives like `/media/device1` and specific folders `/home/eka/dir/dir1`. How can I do this in bleachbit?

edit:

sample of modified path in deepscan.xml

```
<option id="ds_store">
    <label translate="false">.DS_Store</label>
    <description>Delete the files</description>
    <warning>This option is slow.</warning>
    <action command="delete" search="deep" cache="false" regex="^\.DS_Store$" path="/media/device1"/>
 </option>
```

initial result of `python bleachbit.py --preset -c`

```
 deepscans={u'/home/eka': [{'regex': u'\\.[Bb][Aa][Kk]$', 'nregex': '', 'cache': False, 'command': u'delete', 'path': u'/home/eka'}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of BleachBit 2.0, deep scan defaults to the home user directory. There is not a way in the GUI to change it, but I think this will work

1. Copy the deepscan.xml that came with BleachBit to `~/.config/bleachbit/cleaners`
2. Change `id="deepscan"` to `id="mydeepscan"`
3. Add the attribute `path="/media/device1"` to each `<action>` element

Then a new DeepScan option will show up, and you can select it.

You may also want to change the `<label>` elements too.

---

Update, here is a working, tested example of an option that cleans logs in `/var/log` instead of in the user home directory. Notice there is an attribute `path=`

`<option id="log">

    <label>Log</label>

    <description>Delete the logs</description>

    <action command="delete" search="deep" cache="false" path="/var/log" regex="\.log$"/>
  </option>`

Please note that this XML goes into a CleanerML .xml file. In my case, I added it to the existing deepscan.xml, but it could go into a new .xml file that is in the right folder.

Comment: it didn't worked. I went  and open deepscan.xml in `~/.config/bleachbit/cleaners` then changed `cleaner id="mydeepscan"` then added the path attribute to every action element `<action path="/media/device1" command="delete" search="deep" regex="\.[Bb][Aa][Kk]$" cache="false"/>`. Then I tried to deepclean. it still shows the home directory on preview

Comment: @eka After saving the new .xml file, did you notice a new cleaner in the GUI? And did you check the boxes? This is to troubleshoot where the problem may be

Comment: No I can't see any new cleaner in it. For clarity I have not installed bleachbit in my system instead I am using the portable python version from https://github.com/bleachbit/bleachbit  `python bleachbit.py --gui`. I changed the deepscan.xml file in this one.

Comment: @eka I am also using the Git version without installation. I am on Ubuntu 18.10. I made a new cleaner to clean logs in /var/log, and it worked. If you are running without installation and are OK with modifying the original deepscan.xml file, then you do not need to change the id="deepscan". If you want to adjut the path on the existing options, just add the `path="media/device`" to each action element. If you still have trouble, post your deepscan.xml to a pastebin or gist.

Comment: @eka By the way, I edited my answer to show the log cleaner that I tested.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I have edited my question and added more information to it. After all changes also bleachbit is using the default drive. Any idea why this happening.

Comment: @eka The log 'regex': u'\\.[Bb][Aa][Kk]$' does not match the XML regex="^\.DS_Store$", so it looks like you selected a different option. The log is the backup option, and the XML is the DS_Store option

Comment: I only pasted the ds_store option here but added path to everything inside that xml backup, thumbs_db, tmp all the thing